# Linq get rows by enum values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, enums

Here is my enum values defined

```
public enum authaccess
{ read=0,create=1,update=2,delete=4}
```

As a Access Table looks like as below.

```
|id  | tablename |columnname|permitted|
|----|-----------|----------|---------|
|1   | cms       |header    |3        |
|2   | cms       |footer    |2        |
|3   | cms       |content   |7        |
```

read access is permitted for all content, while 3 is for(create + update), and 7 for all rights.

As I need (x) button enabled in div where loggedInUser has delete authority

Using Linq, I used

```
new DbContext().tbl_access.where(k=>k.permitted > authaccess.delete){divid.class.add('close')}
```

but could not find a way to **get a list of contents that can be changed by user** ie 3 or (authaccess.create + authaccess.update)

[Clarification on edit]
The resultant table should be

```
|id  | tablename |columnname|permitted|
|----|-----------|----------|---------|
|1   | cms       |header    |3        |
|2   | cms       |footer    |2        |
```

Because (header and footer) include create+update level access which is less than or equal to 3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which type of LINQ is this? And if it's LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework), is the enum also mapped as enum? And is is a flagged enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `authaccess` has values for bit masking. For your requested create + update, a possible way to write your Linq is:

```
new DbContext().tbl_access
    .Where(k => (k.permitted & (int)authaccess.create) > 0) && 
                (k.permitted & (int)authaccess.update) > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks,
I like it this way

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
var authAccessFilter = (int)authaccess.create + (int)authaccess.update;
var records = new DbContext().tbl_access.Where(k => k.permitted <= authAccessFilter).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry, the problem was not clearly understood. I have added few lines below to clarify the requirement.

Comment: <= is not recommended, when later values on enum  do not override the previous roles.